# Sections within a div not recognised in browser

Tags: css, html

Hi I have the following code, this is just an example but explains my principle

```
<div class='main_content'>
<p>Hello</p>
<section>
<h6>Test Section</h6>
</section>
</div>
```

Hello is being displayed within the div and space is being allocated however the  content is not influencing the height, (it is however displaying in the dom tree within the div)

Any ideas please

Comment: Did you try to add `section { display: block; }`?

Comment: What do you mean with "the content is not influencing the height"? The height of what? What does the CSS look like? Are you aware then IE doesn't support "custom" (or in this case HTML5) elements?

Comment: I have used mozilla firefox, ie8 using the html5 shiv ack mentioned below. and have inluded the following css to style the html5 elements

Comment: /* HTML5-specific CSS setup */
article,aside,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}

Answer (score 0):

For IE to treat `<section>` as a block-level element, you'll need the html5 shiv hack:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

More info:

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/semantics.html
- http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/